# is that an erroneous use of "steppes": "the high Himalaya in the northern steppes.."

Tags: word-meaning

A [quote](http://www.saritaholidays.com/bhutan-faq.php) from a page about Bhutan:

> The rugged east, visited by few Western travellers, the high Himalaya in the northern **steppes** separates the kingdom from Tibet.

Isn't that an erroneous use of the term **steppes**? A steppe is a region characterized by plains. How could high mountains be "in the steppes"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a relevant picture found by Googling **Tibet steppes**...

[image]

Just because [*steppes*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/steppe) (semiarid grass-covered plains) are essentially flat doesn't mean they're low-altitude, or that there can't be *any* mountains in the vicinity.

---

Having said that, OP's cited text isn't really a valid sentence. Stripping out a couple of syntactically-irrelevant non-restrictive clauses, we've got...

> *The rugged east, the high Himalaya separates the kingdom from Tibet.*

That could *just about* be made "acceptable" by inserting a comma after *Himalaya* (making *"the high Himalaya"* an optional alternative term for *"the rugged east"*). But when those additional clauses are included, I think the phrasing becomes excessively tortuous. Better might be...

> *The rugged east, visited by few Western travellers, **includes** the high Himalaya in the northern steppes, **that/which** separates the kingdom from Tibet.*

Comment: Thank you, @FumbleFingers! What confused me was this combination of "**high** Himalayas **in the** northern steppes", creating a (wrong) mental picture of steppes dominating and peaks sprinkled here and there. And in Russian the word "steppe" usually means something "all the way to the horizon and beyond".

Comment: Apparently [English **steppe** came from Russian](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=steppe), but they don't know where the Russian term originated from (or exactly what it meant) in the first place. So it's quite possible the more general anglicized usage has diverged somewhat from the Russian original. I tend to think of *steppes* as "high altitude" - probably mainly because I think of them as *cold* flat, arid, treeless plains. The confusing bits in your text for *me* are the "error" as discussed above, and the singular usage *Himalaya* which I don't recall coming across before.